# Regex: Differentiate boundary match ^ and Negation

Tags: java, regex

I'm learning about regex, and I've writed a method that get numbers from a string:

```
replaceAll("[^\\d]","");
```

The method above returns a string with only digits.
But I only get a positive number... What if I want to get a negative number?

So, I've tried to change the pattern to consider only digits and the character "-" (only in beginning). As follows:

```
replaceAll("[^\\d&&[^[^-]]","");

replaceAll("[^\\d]&&^[^-]","");
```

And several others... But I didn't get the result I want. Maybe it can be a silly mistake, because but I can't figure out.

So what is the right way to write a regex that excludes digits and the character "-" only in beginning?

Example: if I input:

```
$/65*(85gg78,     I get 658578.
2-340,            I get 2340, And:
-2-340,           I get -2340
```

Thanks!

Comment: `&&` is not meaningful in a regex. I am still not sure what you want to do. Please include a "before and after" examples. For example, what should happen to `--28xxx8`? `^` is negation when first character in `[^...]`; a normal character elsewhere in `[...]`; and start of line outside `[...]`.

Comment: @amadan `&&` is the character class intersection operator

Comment: @Amadan I just edited with some examples

Comment: @Bohemian: TIL... Apparently only Java and Ruby though? Good to know.

Comment: @Bohemian: Works in [Ruby](http://rubular.com/r/tz61nxfLaY) and [Java](http://fiddle.re/mphp16), but not in [Python](https://regex101.com/r/yV8fC5/1#python), [JS](https://regex101.com/r/yV8fC5/1#javascript) or [PCRE](https://regex101.com/r/yV8fC5/1#pcre). Also, [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclassintersect.html) says "Character class intersection is supported by Java and by Ruby 1.9 and later."

Comment: Can you please update your post along with what it should match and what not

Comment: @Saleem: He doesn't want to match, he wants to *replace*. The inputs and outputs are given in the OP.

Comment: I would do it the other way about: scan for numbers, with `"-?[0-9]+"`, and ignore everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in two steps, first removing non-digits but leaving minus signs, then removing all minus signs except where it's the very first character.

```
String parsed = input.replaceAll("[^\\d-]","").replaceAll("(?<!^)-", "");
```

So `"foo-2-3bar" --> "-23"`, but `"foo2-3bar" --> "23"`

---

FYI `\D` is the same as `[^\d]`.

Comment: Thank you for answering! But it works fine only if I have the minus sign "-" in beginning folowed by a digit, but in cases like -2-3, I get -2-3.

Comment: If you would indicate to only allow '-' at the beginning, it would be `(?!^-\\d)\\D`

Comment: @tdm yes I assumed there would be at most one minus sign in there - that's some pretty messed up input you're dealing with. What do you want to be returned for input `"-2-3"` - `"-23"`?

Comment: @Bohemian Exactly! For input -2-3, it should return -23. Thanks to your code I changed only to replaceAll ("(?!^-)\\D") that works also in cases like --2-3

Comment: @tdm your solution will turn `"foo-2-3"` into `"23"`. If that's not what you want, see my edited answer for how to make that work too.

Comment: @Bohemian You're right! Thanks a lot! Now I'm curious, as I know the basics of regex, what does it mean the pattern "(? <!^)-" ? Prior to this edit, I discover you were using called lookaround, now is it the same thing?

Comment: @tdmsoares Yes `(?<!^)-` uses one of look-around mechanisms. To be more precise it uses negative-look-behind. It simply ensures that `-` we are matching will not have before it `(?<! ... )` start of string (represented by `^`). More info about lookaround http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html and second part http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround2.html

Comment: @Pshemo Thanks for the tutorial!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
String data = "" +
        "$/65*(85gg78,\n" +
        "2-340,       \n" +
        "-2-340,";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)[+-]?\\d+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);
while (matcher.find()){
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Based on input text as:

```
$/65*(85gg78,
2-340,       
-2-340,
```

Regex will match

```
65
85
78
2
-340
-2
-340
```

Comment: I agree that matching is better than replacing for this job, but it's not that simple; in Java, `matches()` expects the regex to match the whole string.  For this, you would need the `find()` method, which is found only in the `Matcher` class.

Comment: @AlanMoore, I agree. I was just giving hint to OP how one can use simple regex. but I'll update code ready to copy/paste :)