# Regex not working in method replaceAll() - Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I asked a question here: [Regex: Differentiate boundary match ^ and Negation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36144789/regex-differentiate-boundary-match-and-negation/36144843#36144843) about a regex to be applied in method replaceAll(), to get a String with only digits and the minus sign (-) to allow negative numbers as well. I run the follow and it works fine in my java interpreter:

```
String onlyDigits = currencyStringValue.replaceAll("[\\D-]","").replaceAll("(?<!^)-","");
```

> If I input: --25#54d51 -> Returns: -255451
>
> 25#54-d51 -> Returns: 255151
>
> -25#54d51 -> Returns: -255451
>
> dz-255451 -> Returns: -255451

But I'm trying the same thing in Android Studio, and only returns digits,  debugging the app, I notice the onlyDigits get only numbers 0-9, ignoring the minus sign (-) in beginning...

What is it wrong and if there is a problem in code or solution, how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: `replaceAll("[\\D]","")` removes any non-digit character including `-`. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Try [`String onlyDigits = currencyStringValue.replaceAll("[^-\\d]","").replaceAll("(?<!^)-","");`](http://ideone.com/Jh7gKG).

Comment: @Pshemo what a silly mistake I did...

Comment: @Pshemo I changed to replaceAll("[\\D-]","").replaceAll("(?<!^)-","") and the problem kept. But I corrected my code with the suggestion from the answer below and now It works fine

Comment: Isn't that same solution which you already get here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36144843/1393766?

Comment: @Pshemo No... The only difference is [^\\d-] to [^-\\d]. While in my interpreter runs well, in Android doesn't work...

Comment: Interesting. I am not Android developer so can't test it but both cases should work same way. I would suspect that `[^\\d-]` would be even less confusing since `-` will not be part of any range here. If `[^-\\d]` works here but `[^\\d-]` is not then it looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `\D` that matches *any character but a digit*. With the first replacement operation you remove all minuses together with other non-digits.

The solution is simple: turn `\D` into a negated character class `[^\d]` and add a hyphen into it so as to avoid removing minuses before the next replaceAll call.

Use

```
String onlyDigits = currencyStringValue.replaceAll("[^-\\d]","").replaceAll("(?<!^)-","");
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/Jh7gKG)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Before it was my mistake, but I corrected and the problem happened again. But now thanks to you it works fine!